# Как в phpstorm в режиме Debug (Live Edit) подключать изображения с компьютера?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, phpstorm

```
<img src="img.jpg" alt="">
```

При попытке подключить изображение выдается ошибка: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

**Вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы можно было подключать изображения на страницу в режиме Debug (Live Edit)?**

Comment: а где лежит `"img.jpg"` - в той же папке, где `.html`? и при чем тут отладка или live edit?

Comment: Почему-то изображение не появляется, если запускать файл через php storm, но если запустить его через xampp, то всё работает.

Comment: ну веб серверы разные, routing по-разному работает.

Comment: И происходит еще одна мифическая вещь (уже в другом проекте).
Я в шапке сайта разметил изображение logo1.jpg, которое находилось в папке с файлом .html. Потом я решил взять другой логотип (который разместил уже в другой папке), удалил logo1.jpg из каталога, в котором находился .html и поменял в коде путь к новому изображению логотипа. Но происходит странная вещь: если запускать .html через php storm, то почему-то в коде страницы содержится изображение logo1.jpg. Даже если из кода .html удалить тег img, то в коде страницы после перезапуска всё равно останется img с путем к logo1.jpg.

Comment: Но если запускать через xampp, то при изменении пути к изображению в теге img, в коде страницы тоже будут происходить изменения, а также при удалении тега img, в коде страницы этот тег успешно удаляется.

Comment: И еще в этом проекте я подключаю еще одно изображение, которое не появляется при запуске через php storm (отладка и обычный запуск), но появляется при запуске через xampp